# sending "ping" output to a variable

Tags: scripting, tcl, router

I am trying to ping some ip addresses in my router. I use this code:

```
for {set n 0} {$n < 10} {incr n} {puts [exec "ping 199.99.$n.1]}
```

but this will show the output.
the issue is that I don't want to see the output. I would like to send that output into another variable and the search the content of variable with "regexp" and get the result, and do the rest of the story. 
but I don't know how I can do that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `set` command. The `puts` command prints it's argument.

```
set pingOutput [exec ping "199.99.$n.1"]
```

Or `append` if you want all IP's results in one variable.

```
set allPingOutput ""
for {set n 0} {$n < 10} {incr n} {
    append allPingOutput [exec ping "199.99.$n.1"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the ping with the -c flag:
ping -c 1 10.0.1.1

Not sure how to do it in tcl but in php for example:

Answer (score 0):

It is very important to  use  `ping -c1 <IP address>` , otherwise the script will never end as the ping process never ends :)

My code uses an array of results of every IP

```
for {set i 2 } {$i < 10} {incr i} {

catch {if {[regexp {bytes from} [exec ping -c1 192.168.12.$i]]} { 
          set flag "reachable" 
        } else     { set flag "not reachable"}

set  result(192.168.12.$i) $flag
} 
}
parray result
```

OUTPUT :

result(192.168.12.2) = reachable

result(192.168.12.3) = reachable

result(192.168.12.5) = reachable

result(192.168.12.6) = reachable

result(192.168.12.7) = reachable

result(192.168.12.9) = reachable

Instead of storing and manipulating , I used regexp .